# Click image within slider to show text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On  http://www.socialstudent.co.uk/stackoverflow/ I am trying to work out a way to make it so when you tap an image on mobile, it makes text appear below it and a button. Then if you tap it again it disappears.

I have tried the usual ways in JS but none seem to work. Any ideas on how I can get that to happen would be great!

An example would be this - http://jsfiddle.net/ZECTP/ but with the image being tapped on mobile.

JS off jsfiddle as was required:

```
  $(function () {
        var div = $('#showOrHideDiv');
        $('#action').click(function () {
            div.fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });
```

HTML off jsfiddle as was required:

```
<a id="action" href="#">hide/show text</a>
<div id="showOrHideDiv" style="display: none;">hidden text</div>
```

It needs to be in addition to the text which is on the image, as below text and a button needs to appear.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your code the fiddle appears to be working?

Comment: That is just an example of what I want to do, but it doesn't work with the current setup.

Comment: how are we going to help you if we don't know the current setup?

Comment: The fiddle appears to be working.. just replace the hide/show with an image...

Answer (score 0):

Check this udpated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwvgzmtq/5/)

I think this is what you are looking for.

**HTML**

```
<figure class = "figure">
    <img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dapino/summer-holiday/96/photo-icon.png" />
    <figcaption class = "figcaption">
        SOME TEXT HERE    
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
    figure {
    font-size: 100%;
}

figcaption {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".figure").click(function(){
    $(".figcaption").toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: This is moving the text, what I need is fresh text to appear on image click!

Comment: if u want something like that then check my edit :) check the fiddle, it's edited

Comment: Hey man, tried this but gives the image I use it on a border and nothing happens onclick. Maybe something to do with the slider I am using? I also moved the <figcaption class = "figcaption">
        SOME TEXT HERE    
    </figcaption>
</figure> out of the slider DIV but broke the slider but worked as the text appeared below.

Comment: you can remove the <figure> and just use the <img> tag. if you can show me the codes it would be a better help. and im willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code of the site you provided and you would need to add this code to get the desired effect. I'm assuming you want to show/hide the text over each image.

```
var elems = $('#my_horizontal_main_stage li');
elems.find('div').hide(); // text hidden by default, or you can use css
elems.on('click', function(e){
    el = $(this);
    el.find('div').fadeToggle('fast');
})
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this but what I need is new text appearing below, have updated my original post to show this.